# SE for coef.merMod coefficients?

Tags: r, lme4, standard-error

Is there a way to get standard errors for the `coef.merMod` method of the `lme4` package, or is it nonsense to compute SE for the coefficients?

Example:

```
library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
coef(fit)

$Subject
    (Intercept)       Days
308    253.6637 19.6662579
309    211.0065  1.8475828
310    212.4449  5.0184061
330    275.0956  5.6529547
331    273.6653  7.3973914
332    260.4446 10.1951153
333    268.2455 10.2436615
334    244.1725 11.5418620
335    251.0714 -0.2848731
337    286.2955 19.0955699
349    226.1950 11.6407002
350    238.3351 17.0814910
351    255.9829  7.4520288
352    272.2687 14.0032993
369    254.6806 11.3395026
370    225.7922 15.2897506
371    252.2121  9.4791309
372    263.7196 11.7513157
```

The `coef.merMod` is simply the sum of `ranef` + `fixef` for each explanatory variable for each level of each grouping factor.

With the `arm` package, you can get standard errors for fixed and random effects with `se.fixef` and `se.ranef` (and `se.coef`, which is, however, only a concatanation of the two first outputs).

My question is: is the SE of coefficients simply coef(ranef) + coef(fixef)? Or do the sums of random and fixed coefficients have no real standard error?

Comment: Thanks, indeed your referred answer is an answer to my question...